# Rails getting started 5.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm programming for the first time in ruby and so I'm doing the 'getting started' tutorial from the official website:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

I have a problem with 5.7. The tutorial says:

> If you submit the form again now, Rails will complain about not
>   finding the show action. That's not very useful though, so let's add
>   the show action before proceeding.

And then there is the following code:

> post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show

But where do I have to put this code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you've depicted is the `show` member for the `posts` resource routes. It's not actually code, but rather, a pattern for URL routing. You can see all your routes in this fashion by typing `rake routes` from the command line.

Breaking down the route:

```
post GET /posts/:id(.:format) posts#show
# `post` => named route name (available by default only to singular routes)
# `GET` => HTTP method
# `/posts/:id(.:format)` => path made accessible by route
# :id => specifies that the argument passed in as `:id` is available to the controller as `params[:id]`
# `posts#show` => controller is `posts`, action is `show`
```

You need to create a corresponding `show` controller action that the route will map to:

```
# app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: ok, I have already done this.
But after that, the tutorial says to add that code but doesn't say where...

Comment: The documentation reads: `let's add the show action before proceeding`. It's referring to the `show` action of the `posts` controller. It is __not__ referring to the following line, which is not even code.

Comment: Thank you, I have found another problem and now that I have fixed, everything works.

Comment: I agree with Lorenzo, the documentation is unclear. As a newbie, I tried putting that "non-code" block in the config/routes.rb file. It sure looks like code of some sort.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this same problem going through the tutorial.  A more direct response to this question is "no where".  The reference to that line int the tutorial is only informational.  It reads in a way that leads you to believe that you are supposed to add it but there is nothing to add.  Just keep going through the rest of the tutorial and all will be well.  Maybe someday the author will read this and fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following (bolded) sentence would make the instructions in 5.7 more clear:

If you submit the form again now, Rails will complain about not finding the show action. That's not very useful though, so let's add the show action before proceeding. **Running 'rake routes`now results in the following:**

`post GET /posts/:id(.:format) posts#show`

Answer (score 1):

If you have the PostsController in your application, then you must have the following in the config/routes.rb

```
resources :posts
```

So that it will generate 7 default routes for the posts controller where show is a default action.

When you do `rake routes` in your console, it will show you all the routes for your application. From those routes, you can get

```
post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#show
```

The above is the routes, not the code. So it states that you have a controller named "posts" and "show" is an action of it. Which can be accessible via '/posts/:id' with "get" method.

Comment: The OP has indicated that they've reached section 5.7 of the tutorial. Presumably, they will have already have added `resources :posts`, since this is specified in section 5.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the private section comes after the def show block

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

def new
end

def create
  #render text: params[:post].inspect
  @post = Post.new(post_params)

  @post.save
  redirect_to @post
end

def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing needs to be added to the config file, as some guys already said, is the information that appears after run the command

> rake routes

Just adding the ***show*** action to the post_controller.rb and the show.html.erb view is enough to be able to post the information and continue with the example.