# 'Getting Started with Rails' tutorial section 5.7 - route syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

It's probably me getting the wrong end of the stick, but here goes..

Following the Ruby on Rails tutorial here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

(Ruby 2.0.0, Rails 4.0)

All good until I get to this section here:

[image: Section 5.7]

If that's a route entry as the text suggests, then it doesn't look like the right syntax to me. I can make it work by changing it to this..

get '/posts/:id(.:format)'  =>    'post#show'

...haaang on... (penny drops)

Looking at it as I type this, it looks like the tutorial is showing the output of the **rake routes** command and expecting me to translate it to the valid route entry syntax?

(Given the copy/paste nature of the rest of the tutorial isn't that a little confusing for Ruby/Rails noobs like myself?)

Same question, different answer here [Rails getting started 5.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400313/rails-getting-started-5-7)

Comment: You are right and it might be a bit confusing. You can submit a pull request to github to change the relevant part to make it more friendly. [Here is the relevant github link](https://github.com/rails/docrails/blob/master/guides/source/getting_started.md)

Comment: Yeah, I had the same problem too, couldn't really figure it out, until I opened `routes.db`, and added the appropriate line similar to others in it.

Comment: +1 for the github info & link - didn't realise that was an option.

Comment: Seems they've rolled the docs back into the main rails project - http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/6/14/docrails-back-to-the-roots/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that the doc needs some updating, since before it tells you to add

```
resources :posts
```

to your `routes.rb` configuration file, which should automatically add all 7 rest routes for you.

The guide tells you that the show action is absent in your **controller**. I think that the whole sentence should be reworded :)

Comment: Phew - glad it wasn't just me. It's very easy to be derailed (see what I did there :-) ) when picking up a new language and framework.